# Why couldn't I start a bounty for 50 rep?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounty

I thought that, in general 50 is the minimum level for a bounty (as an example, this question currently has an open bounty for 50 rep: [Associating chords with scales](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30222/associating-chords-with-scales) )

But when I added a bounty to [my question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30180/i-made-a-chord-sequence-but-im-not-sure-what-key-its-in), the minimum rep I could offer was 100 (I think the levels were 100, 200, 300, 500 though I'm not 100% certain).

I just tried adding another bounty and the levels were all in 50 rep intervals. That was definitely not what I saw previously, bounty reward levels were *all* multiples of 100 so it wasn't just the 50 which was missing.

Why was this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [minimum bounty is 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116476/233816) on a question you have answered yourself. Have you answered that question, and since deleted it? That would still count.

Comment: Ah, the mystery is solved. Good sleuthing :)

Comment: Fortunately the first question I tested this one was one I answered. Then it just took a bit of Google!

Answer (score 2):

You don't link the question you speak about, so I can only guess (since this is the only reason for that I'm aware of): You have put a bounty on the question before. In that case, the next bounty has to be at least the double of the bounty before, until the price reaches 500. This is to prevent users from "bumping their question 'for nothing'".

---

Update, seeing the [question's revision history](https://music.stackexchange.com/posts/30180/revisions), there doesn't seem to be any older bounty on the question. In that case I don't know why a 50 bounty was forbidden to you. To me, it seems as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), I'm not aware of any rule that should have prevented you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I hadn't added a bounty and there wasn't one. Unless I had missed/forgotten it, of course.

Comment: Full info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work